# Installshield VBscribt ExitCode not aborting uninstall

Tags: vb.net, installshield

I have build an installer using installshield 2016.

I have a VB script (running in a custom action) that checks if a database is empty and when it is, the uninstall can take places.

The settings of the custom action are:

- Return Processing: Synchronous (check exit code)
- In-script Execution:Immediate Execution
- Execution Scheduling: Always execute
- Install Exec Sequence: After InstallValidate
- Install Exec Condition: REMOVE="ALL"

The custom action with the script runs and the Message box is shown but the installer ignores the Exitcode = 3.

The VB script:

```
Function CheckService()
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=localhost;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

    objConnection.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING

    set rs = objConnection.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'MonitoringConfiguration'")

    if not rs.EOF then
      recordsCount = cint(rs("cnt"))
    end if

    objConnection.Close

    if recordsCount = 0 then
        CheckService = 1
        Exit Function
    end if

    DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MonitoringConfiguration;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

    objConnection.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING

    set rs = objConnection.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt from ServerSettings")

    if not rs.EOF then
      recordsCount = cint(rs("cnt"))
    end if

    objConnection.Close

    if recordsCount <> 0 then
        x=MsgBox("There are still monitoring services deployed. Please remove them first before remvoing System Monitoring",0,"Unable to Uninstall application")
        CheckService = 3
        Exit Function
    else
        CheckService = 1
        Exit Function
    end if

End Function
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did not mention your [Ignore Error Code](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp22/helplibrary/CA_Settings-VBS.htm#ref-views_2820697808_1095910) selection.  So it is probably wrong.

Comment: This option is in the "Return Processing" normally. Now it is set to "Synchronous (Check exit code). The other option is "Synchronous (Ignores Exit Code).

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the action type Stored in Binary Table [image]

that way you'll be able to force the execution of a single function rather than the entire script.